# In ext.net, how do I align a tabpanel button to the right?

Tags: ext.net

I would like to align the button of the right, but keep the content tabs on the left. This is my code:

```
<ext:TabPanel ID="TabPanel1" runat="server" Height="295" Plain="true" DeferredRender="false" meta:resourcekey="TabPanel1Resource1">
       <TabBar>
          <ext:Button runat="server" Icon="ArrowOut" meta:resourcekey="fullscreenResource1">
             <DirectEvents>
                  <Click OnEvent="edit_fullOpenAdd" />
             </DirectEvents>
          </ext:Button>
        </TabBar>
        <Defaults>
           <ext:Parameter Name="autoScroll" Value="true" Mode="Raw" />
        </Defaults>
           <Items>
               ......the content ......
           </Items>
</ext:TabPanel>
```

Any Ideas?

Thank you!

Edit: I was told to try **tabCls: 'right-tab'**, but I do not know how to implement this.

Comment: Please clarify do you want it to be aligned on the left vertically? Or you still need it at the top and horizontally?

Comment: @DaniilVeriga i would like it top right, vertically aligned with the other tabs. In other words, i have my tabs on the left, then a space, then my button on the complete right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use TabStrip control.
Please see this example: http://examples.ext.net/#/TabPanel/TabStrip/Overview/

[image]

Comment: That is the resource I needed to find my answer. What I really needed was to just add a `<ext:ToolbarFill ID="ToolbarFill1" runat="server" />` before my button!